# App Engine - Custom Domain pointing to subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I hear that now we can do wildcard subdomains on google app engine (I haven't tried it myself, but I believe that's been a new feature added), but can we have a domain point to it?

So

**new.example.com** (works?)

**newexample.com -> new.example.com** (does this work? where newexample.com is acting as new.example.com)

The way I envision newexample.com, this would work as

**newexample.com/blog** in the url, but app engine would support it as **new.example.com/blog**

I guess I am trying to emphasize that I am NOT looking for domain fowarding where newexample.com just forwards users to new.example.com

Thanks!

UPDATE: To clarify, I wasn't meaning naked domain, but a url like this

**www.newexample.com/blog** can work as **new.example.com/blog** or perhaps even more clearly, **new.example.appspot.com/blog**

Answer (score 4):

Yes you just have to use an asterix `*.example.com` when setting up your custom domain in google apps.

> To serve your app on all subdomains within a given higher-level subdomain, you can use wildcard subdomain mapping: enter an asterisk in place of the lowest-level name. For example, entering * will cause your app to be served on all subdomains within your registered domain.

See [Custom domains](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html)

*.yourappid.appspot.com domains work by default.

You **can** add your app to as many different Google Apps accounts (so can use multiple domains), but you can not use domain alias' within Google Apps, as only the primary domain from a google apps account is used.

> Applications that use Google App Engine are not available for users at non-primary domains.

See [Limitations for multiple domains](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is:
Can the "naked" domain such as **newexample.com** (i.e. without anything such as `www.` before it) be served by Google App Engine?

Then the answer is [no - see the FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#naked_domain)

Wildcard subdomains let you have any subdomain the a user enters (e.g. myphotos.example.com, yourphotos.example.com, etc...) be served by Google App Engine without having to set each one up individually.  Although it does require a DNS provider that supports wildcards.

Comment: I clarified my question, but that is not what I was asking. Thanks anyways

Comment: The question is still very confusing.